# ruby shoes oci8 connect issue

Tags: ruby, database, rubygems, shoes, oci8

sorry for my english.

I am interested about ruby shoes gui development, but on my experiments I didn't get to connect to oracle database, I have created a file with a code like this:

```
require 'oci8'
conn = OCI8.new("irodriguez", "irodriguez", "desa")
```

so, when I execute from console:

```
$ ruby oci8.rb
```

all ok, but when I run:

```
$ .shoes/dist/shoes oci8.rb
```

I get `uninitialized constant Object::OCI8 error`

Some help?

Comment: Where is your 'oci8' code located in respect to the Shoes.app? Shoes is a DSL which reorganizes the execution of your code and if you put some Ruby code in the middle of your Shoes app it is not trivial that it will work properly especially variable scope is one aspect you have to read in the Shoes documentation.

Comment: first try the connect and some other dbhandling in a normal ruby script so that you'r sure it's the interaction with shoes what causes the problem, when so, could you publish the entire shoes code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to let Shoes know that it needs to pull in those gems. Do the following to make it work.

```
Shoes.setup do
  gem 'oci8'
end

require 'oci8'
conn = OCI8.new("irodriguez", "irodriguez", "desa")
```